# how to change grocery crud template for RWD?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grocery-crud

I did my application in codeigniter using grocery crud lib. It's work fine.

Now, I want to change it in RWD (Responsive Website Design) mode. I already did RWD in my root CSS file it's work fine. But I used grocery crud in my admin side, I want to change grid and form display in grocery curd in RWD mode. I don't have any ideas about how to change grocery crud template for RWD.

Please someone help for this...

Thanks....

Comment: If you're asking about web design, you should add related tags to your question, this is NOT a CodeIgniter issue, nor CRUD. add related code which indicates your problem.

Comment: thanx 4 ur suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s possible, but it´s not very easy to be done. The first thing you need to do is understand how a grocery crud theme is implemented. The themes are in .../assets/grocery_crud/themes

You will have to look the code of one of the three oficial themes available today:

https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/tree/master/assets/grocery_crud/themes

You could pick one of the themes and implement your changes on top of it. I recommend you try first with the twitter-bootstrap theme (i guess it will be easier to implement RWD on top of it).

If you obtain sucess doing this, i would love to see the results. If you do a great job, you could even add your theme to the grocery crud theme package. It would be a great addition to grocery =)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `$output` in a `div` tag and apply your css to the `div`.